# get what percent of documents contain a feature - quanteda

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I'm trying to understand what % of documents contain a feature using `quanteda`. I know the `dfm_weight()` is available, but I believe the 'prop' feature looks at feature frequency within a document and not across documents.

My goal would be to avoid having to do the `ifelse` statement and keep it all in `quanteda`, but I'm not sure this is possible. The output I'm looking for is a side-by-side bar chart grouped by year that has features along the y-axis and % occurrence in documents along the x. The interpretation here would then be "In 20% of all comments in 2018, people mention the word X, compared to 24% in 2019."

```
library(quanteda)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

df$rownum = 1:nrow(df) # unique ID
dfCorp19 = df %>%
  corpus(df, text_field = 'WhatPromptedYourSearch', docid_field = 'rownum')

x = dfm(dfCorp19,
        remove=c(stopwords(), toRemove),
        remove_numbers = TRUE,
        remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    textstat_frequency(groups ='year') 

x = x %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(prop = ifelse(group=='2019', docfreq/802, docfreq/930))
x = dcast(x,feature ~ group, value.var='prop')
```

Comment: What are the two "sides" of the bars? If it's just % mentioning, then no point putting % not mentioning.

Comment: Sorry I was grouping by year so each bar for a word would be a year. So “ in 2018, Apple was mentioned 20% vs in 2019 it was mentioned 25%”

Comment: where is `df` coming from? could you include a link (maybe Dropbox/GoogleDocs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt using some demo data, where the group is decade.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 1.5.1

docvars(data_corpus_inaugural, "decade") <-
    floor(docvars(data_corpus_inaugural, "Year") / 10) * 10

dfmat <- dfm(corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, decade >= 1970))

target_word <- "nuclear"
```

Now we can just extract a data.frame for the target feature.  Note the `rowSums()` function since otherwise, any slice of a dfm is still a dfm (not a vector).

```r
df <- data.frame(docname = docnames(dfmat),
                 decade = docvars(dfmat, c("decade")),
                 contains_target = rowSums(dfmat[, "nuclear"]) > 0,
                 row.names = NULL)
df
#>         docname decade contains_target
#> 1    1973-Nixon   1970            TRUE
#> 2   1977-Carter   1970            TRUE
#> 3   1981-Reagan   1980           FALSE
#> 4   1985-Reagan   1980            TRUE
#> 5     1989-Bush   1980           FALSE
#> 6  1993-Clinton   1990           FALSE
#> 7  1997-Clinton   1990            TRUE
#> 8     2001-Bush   2000           FALSE
#> 9     2005-Bush   2000           FALSE
#> 10   2009-Obama   2000            TRUE
#> 11   2013-Obama   2010           FALSE
#> 12   2017-Trump   2010           FALSE
```

With that, it's a simple matter to summarize proportions and plot them using some **dplyr** and **ggplot2**.

```r
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(decade) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

library("ggplot2")
g <- ggplot(df2, aes(y = freq, x = decade)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("") + ylab("Proportion of documents containing target word")
g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! So do you think using the docfreq column in textstat_frequency is overkill then if you are just using row sums?

Comment: I ask, because ideally your y-axis of decades would be the top_n words by %.

Comment: The `docfreq` column from the `textstat_frequency()` data.frame is also good - e.g. `extstat_frequency(dfmat, groups = "decade")` but then you need to divide the `docfreq` by the number of documents in each group to get a proportion. You could do this using `table(docvars(dfmat, "decade")` and merging that with the group value from the textstat output, then dividing to get a proportion.

Comment: perfect, thank you! That is what I was thinking/looking for